What exactly is the definition of a UMP unbiased test?
I am solving exercises from section 8.3 of Hogg and McKean's "Introduction to Mathematical Statistics." I cannot proceed because the authors have not formally defined UMPU test even though they have given the definition for UMP test.
Context: In exercise $8.3.8,$ authors ask us to show that the LRT principle for testing $H_0:\theta = \theta_0$ against $H_1:\theta \neq \theta_0$ leads to the inequality $\lvert \overline{x}-\theta_0\rvert \geq c,$ where $\overline{x}$ is the realized mean of the random sample from $N(\theta,1),$ and where $\theta_0$ is specified. Then they ask

(a) Is this a uniformly most powerful test of $H_0$ against $H_1$?
(b) Is this a uniformly most powerful unbiased test of $H_0$ against $H_1$?

In fact, in the text, authors have shown that there is no UMP test for such a two sided hypothesis. There are SE posts as well (like this one) that show this. The issue for me is part (b).
What exactly is the definition of a UMP unbiased test? I am stuck here because there is no formal definition for this in the text. There is just one line that says

There it was shown that no UMP test exists for this situation. If we restrict attention to the class of unbiased tests (Definition $8.1.2$), then a theory of best tests can be constructed; see Lehmann ($1986$).

Definition $8.1.2$ is given in one of my previous posts, where it basically says that if $\theta \in \omega_1$, the alternative parameter set, then $P_\theta(X \in C) \geq \alpha,$ where $C$ critical region with level $\alpha$. A UMP test is a test defined by this critical region if it is a best critical region of size $\alpha$ to test $H_0$ against each simple hypothesis in $H_1$.
My Question: What exactly is the precise mathematical definition of a UMPU test? What exactly are we expected to show for part (b) of this exercise problem?

First, it is apt to understand what unbiasedness means and why it is desirable. Formalization of the concept for the particular context can be delayed for a para or two.
In decision theory, a decision procedure is unbiased if the realized rule is closer to the correct decision than a wrong one, on average.
Naturally such procedures are appealing.
What would that look like in hypotheses testing problems?
For a test $\varphi$ to be unbiased, $$\Pr(\textrm{reject null when it is false})\nless\Pr(\textrm{reject null when it is true}).$$
That is, $\varphi$ should not be more likely to reject the null hypothesis when it is true than when it is false.
This leads to the following definition:
Definition $1:$ A size $\alpha$ test $\varphi$ for testing $\mathrm H_0: P\in \mathcal P_0$ versus $\mathrm H_1: P\in \mathcal P_1$ is unbiased if $\alpha\leq \inf_{P\in\mathcal P_1} \underbrace{\int \varphi~\mathrm dP}_{=:\beta_\varphi(P)}.$
Definition $2:$ $\varphi$ is UMP unbiased–$\alpha$ if

$\varphi$ is of size $\alpha, $
For each $P\in\mathcal P_1, $ and for any other unbiased test $\psi, $ $\beta_\varphi(P)\geq \beta_\psi(P).$

As for the other question, check for UMPU level $\alpha$ tests for one-dimensional exponential families. That would provide insight.
--
Reference:
A Graduate Course on Statistical Inference, Bing Li, G. Jogesh Babu, Springer Science$+$Business, $2019, $ sec. $3.4.1.$

Nice answer. Just adding that the newer editions of Lehmann's Testing Statistical Hypotheses (with Romano) have 2 chapters devoted to the proofs involved in these definitions.
